# How can I reference a cell into a text string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building small blocks of content in HTML and want to only switch out a part of it (image URL in `img src=""` or description between `< p > < / p >`

So I have `< img src =" " >` in one cell - but would like to insert the URL from another cell.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URDSbWGWK_DZW3G-T5bqfQ0SJz-50NTpuP07Z36NkNk/edit?usp=sharing). Be sure to accept answer if if scratches your itch! ;-)

- `CHAR(34)` is the character code for double quotes.

Some screenshots to illustrate:

**Data:**
[image: Data]

**Formulas:**
[image: Formulas]

So just type new path to a file name in cell **F1**.

Have just shown you how to split img tag apart and rejoin it back together.

- **A1** contains original HTML *img* tag.
- **G1** would show how the full tag would appear after updating **F1**.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
="< img src ="""&B1&""" >"
```

[image: 0]

---

```
="< p >"&B2&"< / p >"
```

[image: 0]